# Create variable JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP file like that:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">product display name:</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">{{api.productDisplayName}}</div>
</div>
```

{{api.productDisplayName}} is a value that I retrieve of a precedent page.
I want to create a variable to have something like that for example

```
var test = {{api.productDisplayName}}.replace("_","") + "test"
```

I don't know the syntax.

Can you help me to know the syntax to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: where do you want to use this `test` variable? If you want to use it in your `JSP` then there are other ways.

Comment: I want to use in this JSP file yes

Answer (score 0):

If you want data that to be accessed across multiple pages, use session to store it in first page like `request.getSession().setAttribute("field1", value1);`

Access it using scriplet tag in the second page

```
<% String test = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("field1"); %>
```

Comment: Where I put this ?

Comment: updated the answer. set it in session in first page & get it from session in second page

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done using the JSTL core and function libraries. You have to first include these libraries in your JSP like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
```

Create the variable `test` at the place where you need it like:

```
<c:set var="test" value="${fn:replace(api.productDisplayName, "_", "")}"></c:set>
```

Finally use the `test` like `${test}` where you need it.